# C# Excel Function - unreachable code detected

Tags: c#, excel, function, unreachable-code

I'm attempting to create a function class in C# for use in an excel Automation add-in. Using the simple code below, I was wanting to add the values in a range that match the colour that the user selects (for example, sum Range("A1:A10") where the cell colour is the same as "B1" would be: colourSum(A1:A10,B1).

```
    public double ColourSum(Range RangeToSum, Range cellContainingColourToSum)
    {
        double currentTotal = 0;
        //return 0; this code is edited from my original posting, due to posting error
        for (int i = 0; i < RangeToSum.Cells.Count;i++) //error at 'int i'
        {
            double iColour = RangeToSum.Interior.ColorIndex(i);
            if (iColour == cellContainingColourToSum.Interior.ColorIndex)
            {
                currentTotal = currentTotal + RangeToSum.Value2(i);
                //return currentTotal;

            }

        }
        return currentTotal;
    }
```

Unfortunately, the above code returns "Unreachable code detected" on line 4. The code example I've given is a simplified example of what I actually want to do but illustrates my point quite well. Is there a problem with my code, or can I write in a better way to avoid this problem?

Thanks,
Rico.

To conclude the question, the following code worked completely (changing for(int i...with foreach (Range r...):

```
    public double ColourSum(Range RangeToSum, Range cellContainingColourToSum)
    {
        double currentTotal = 0;
        foreach (Range r in RangeToSum)
        {
            double iColour = r.Interior.ColorIndex;
            if (iColour == cellContainingColourToSum.Interior.ColorIndex)
            {
                currentTotal = currentTotal + r.Value2;
            }
        }
        return currentTotal;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The minute your code hits the line:

```
return 0;
```

it will exit, there's no way for it to reach the rest of the code. Remove the line.

Comment: Thanks. I entered that erroneously when trying to find a solution to the problem, I mistakenly added it back in before posting here. Unfortunately, removing it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Are you still getting the same error message or is the error now with the loop declaration (I see you've marked "//error at 'int i'")

Comment: Actually, I'm speaking rubbish. On re-building the code, it seems to have worked. The function itself produces "VALUE#", but that's probably another issue. Thanks for your help, all three of you!

Answer (score 3):

When the line `return 0` is hit, the function ends, and nothing after that is executed.  Hence, it is unreachable code.  Remove this line to get the function to behave properly.

Comment: Thanks but see above, removing that line doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You're returning 0 before you get to the loop. Thats why the code is unreachable.

```
return 0;
```

Comment: Thanks but see above, removing that line doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps your dll is not compiled and replaced in the output directory. You must clean-rebuild all the code. (will be good if you could delete everything manually from output folder).

If this dll is added as a project reference then delete and re-add the project reference. May be it works that way.